# Acts_as_taggable_on link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I installed the Acts as taggable on plugin to my 'Post' model, however I'm unable to call up a list of posts tagged with certain tag.

Here's what I have in show.

```
<%= link_to tag.name, posts_path(:view =>'tag', :tag => tag.name) %><% end %>
```

Except when I click on it, it shows all posts. I want it to show just the posts tagged with that keyword...what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which acts as taggable are you using?  Looks like there's a plugin, a gem, one on steriods, one based on the one on steriods, etc.

Regardless, I'd like to see what's in your posts controller to handle the posts_path.  I'm guessing whatever is there is doing a find all instead of using the tag name to limit results.

Comment: I'm using   config.gem "acts-as-taggable-on", :source => "http://gemcutter.org"

Yep you are right, I looked in the log and it is finding all posts, instead of just by tags.

def index
    @posts = current_user.posts.all
    Post.tagged_with("awesome", :on => :tags) # => []
end

I'm trying to use the documentation, but not entirely sure what to do next.

Comment: I changed Post controller to this:
@flits = current_user.flits.find_tagged_with ['test']
and it works, but I'm unable to pass in the tag, so it always finds the articles with test only. In other words, no matter the tag, it only finds the tags tagged with test.

Comment: I figured it out, you just need to pass in the tag with
@flits = Flit.find_tagged_with(params[:tag]) and it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your controller code so that it reads something like:

```
@posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag], :on => 'tags')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing...

## index view

```
 <% job.tags.each do |tag| %>
    <div class="tag"><%= link_to(tag, jobs_path(tag: tag.name), method: :get) %></div>
 <% end %>
```

## index action in the controller

```
if params[:tag]
  @search_term = params[:tag]
  @jobs = Job.tagged_with(@search_term)
end
```